# How do I get further help if the answers I received don't work?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, wrong-answers

I've asked [How to test if a shape and a panel are at the same location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063009/how-to-test-if-a-shape-and-a-panel-are-at-the-same-location) on Stack Overflow, but I'm not getting the answer I need.
Either the answer doesn't work, or my knowledge of Delphi is too small to understand. When I ask them to explain, or help me, they don't answer.

I desperately need an answer, and I don't have enough reputation to set a bounty.

Comment: Your question has three answers, and you only have a comment in one of them. If none of your comments there has been deleted, I would not say you asked, and they are not replying back.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, they've been deleted. On the top-rated answer the OP had commented something along the lines of `it doesn't work` and `plz help`, which is probably why the answerer stopped responding. Craig, if possible always be constructive. People are more than willing to help but it's better to ask for clarification than just saying it doesn't work.

Comment: ok thanks ill try that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can improve your question. Edit it.  By doing so, It will be pushed in the active questions queue.

- Make your question title interesting but informative
- Post with the proper tags. If appropriate with high viewed tags
- Put effort in your question, give details and avoid chatting. Too long questions scare off
- If that doesn't help then put a bounty on your question

Answer (score 1):

"(help me) debug my code" questions are not a great fit for stackoverflow.com. Your question is a wall of code, asking people to scale it and help you. Good questions result from boiling the problem down to a very specific question. "How do I make a game where people shoot at panels" is not nearly specific enough.

And why would you want to program a game in Delphi in the first place?

Comment: Because its a school project and we have to use Delphi. What would you use if you were making a game?